# Signalr can't connect to server. Error #400

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr

I have problem. 
When I Want to connect to Server ( Windows 2012 Server ) this error appear on firebug:

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
>   http://sepehri.dotnetco.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=Kqd%2BPRtv8SMD8IhlEEBeZZm%2FX5DHTlIzIz1Kr4qho%2B5W%2FSN6bZXg4KSzeZhyvalwJJinrm5kVge9CUlVZkI%2B51jQB6luxwSOnztpirH8ERiwDYq1kIyDWz8XiiEsftHO&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mobilehub%22%7D%5D&tid=7"

You can try it yourself 
[Here](http://sepehri.dotnetco.com/websocket.aspx)

Comment: there is no problem with Https.